# how to create a custom popup menu with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a popup menu when clicking on a button from the appbar .. i want something like this to appear:

[image]

is there a way to do this in flutter? a package or something?

Comment: One of solutions is create your own widget and show/hide it on tap on menu button

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky how to create a widget which is shaped in this shape?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky if you can please give me an example of this?

Answer (score 19):

I tried, but I've faced some problems with showing subwidget exactly this way. So, here two solutions:

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool _menuShown = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    Animation opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationController);
    if (_menuShown)
      animationController.forward();
    else
      animationController.reverse();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            _menuShown = !_menuShown;
          });
        })],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: opacityAnimation,
              child: _ShapedWidget(),
            ),
            right: 4.0,
            top: 16.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ShapedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  _ShapedWidget();
  final double padding = 4.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape:
          _ShapedWidgetBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(padding)), padding: padding),
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding).copyWith(bottom: padding * 2),
            child: SizedBox(width: 150.0, height: 250.0, child: Center(child: Text('ShapedWidget'),),),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class _ShapedWidgetBorder extends RoundedRectangleBorder {
  _ShapedWidgetBorder({
    @required this.padding,
    side = BorderSide.none,
    borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero,
  }) : super(side: side, borderRadius: borderRadius);
  final double padding;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.width - 8.0 , rect.top)
      ..lineTo(rect.width - 20.0, rect.top - 16.0)
      ..lineTo(rect.width - 32.0, rect.top)
      ..addRRect(borderRadius
          .resolve(textDirection)
          .toRRect(Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height - padding)));
  }
}
```

In this case subwidget is below appbar

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool _menuShown = false;

  @override
  void initState() {


    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Animation opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationController);
    if (_menuShown)
      animationController.forward();
    else
      animationController.reverse();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            _menuShown = !_menuShown;
          });    
        }),
          Positioned(
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: opacityAnimation,
              child: _ShapedWidget(onlyTop: true,),
            ),
            right: 4.0,
            top: 48.0,
          ),    
          ],)],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: opacityAnimation,
              child: _ShapedWidget(),
            ),
            right: 4.0,
            top: -4.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}  

class _ShapedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  _ShapedWidget({this.onlyTop = false});
  final double padding = 4.0;
  final bool onlyTop;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape:
          _ShapedWidgetBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(padding)), padding: padding),
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding).copyWith(bottom: padding * 2),
            child: onlyTop ? SizedBox(width: 150.0, height: 20.0,) :  SizedBox(width: 150.0, height: 250.0, child: Center(child: Text('ShapedWidget'),),),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class _ShapedWidgetBorder extends RoundedRectangleBorder {
  _ShapedWidgetBorder({
    @required this.padding,
    side = BorderSide.none,
    borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero,
  }) : super(side: side, borderRadius: borderRadius);
  final double padding;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.width - 8.0 , rect.top)
      ..lineTo(rect.width - 20.0, rect.top - 16.0)
      ..lineTo(rect.width - 32.0, rect.top)
      ..addRRect(borderRadius
          .resolve(textDirection)
          .toRRect(Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height - padding)));
  }
}
```

In this case top of subwidget is on appbar, but appbar has to have 0.0 elevation

Actually, both of these solutions are not complete in my opinion, but it can help you to find what you need

Comment: i want to ask about something in the first code ... when i click on the button the popup is displayed immediately .. and then when i click again to make it disappear .. there is a lag till its gone ... how to remove this lag?

Comment: I don't know. Only thing I can think about - try to make release built. In debug there is enough troubles with animations

Comment: i noticed that the popup container will take place of the screen when its there or not .. i have a listview under it .. and i can't scroll in the popup boundaries .. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try to change `FadeTransition` to `ScaleTransition`

Comment: I have a small question.. i made the menu on the left side not in the right side .. and i just want to move the rectangle on the top also to the left side of the menu .. how to do so? what shall i change?

Comment: In `Positioned` set `left` instead of `right`, and inside `getOuterPath` method edit path - remove `rect.width - ` - all three. I think, that's all

Answer (score 6):

It might be too late for an answer. But this can be simply achieved by using `OverlayEntry` widget. We create a widget of that shape and pass it to `OverlayEntry` widget and then use `Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry)` to show the overlay and `overlayEntry.remove` method to remove it.

Here is a medium link to create a [Custom DropDown Menu](https://medium.com/@gshubham030/custom-dropdown-menu-in-flutter-7d8d1e026c6b)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [flutter_portal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal) which works like Overlay/OverlayEntry but in a declarative way. You can use it for implementing custom tooltips, context menus, or dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

```
                CustomPopupMenu(
                  pressType: PressType.singleClick,
                  controller: menu,
                  arrowColor: AppColor.white,
                  menuBuilder: () => ClipRect(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                            ComponentSize.container1height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                            ComponentSize.conatiner1width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              ComponentSize.borderradius),
                          color: AppColor.white,
                        ),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: Details.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                   
                                   do somthing

                                  },
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left:
                                                ComponentSize.paddingleft),
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          Details[index],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontFamily: 'Taml_001'),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left:
                                                ComponentSize.paddingleft),
                                        child: Text(Details[index],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: AppColor.black
                                                    .withOpacity(
                                                        ComponentSize
                                                            .opacity1),
                                                fontSize: ComponentSize
                                                    .containerfontsize)),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const Divider(),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )),
                  child: Container(
                    color: AppColor.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: ComponentSize.paddingbottom,
                        bottom: ComponentSize.paddingtop,
                        left: ComponentSize.padding1left),
                    width: ComponentSize.container2width,
                    height: ComponentSize.container2height,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: ComponentSize.textcontainerwidth,
                                height: ComponentSize.textcontainerheight,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  child: Text(
                                    Tamil,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontFamily: 'Taml_001'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: ComponentSize.textcontainerwidth,
                                height: ComponentSize.textcontainerheight,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  child: Text(
                                    English,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.expand_more,
                            size: ComponentSize.iconarrowsize,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: It would be nice if you include what this approach is doing to answer the question `How to create a custom popup menu with flutter?`. Answers with just code tend to be downvoted. Also, a screenshot would be a bonus!

Answer (score 0):

```
  This is custom Tooltipwidget. You can apply this widget to shape attribute. For example PopupmenuButton(shape: TooltipShapeWidget());

  class TooltipShapeWidget extends ShapeBorder {
  const TooltipShapeWidget();

  final BorderSide _side = BorderSide.none;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry _borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(_side.width);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final path = Path();

    path.addRRect(
  
_borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect).deflate(_side.width),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final path = Path();
    final rrect = _borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect);

    path.moveTo(0, 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 30, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 20, -10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 10, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(rrect.width, 0, rrect.width, 10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width, rrect.height - 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
    rrect.width, rrect.height, rrect.width - 10, rrect.height);
    path.lineTo(10, rrect.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, rrect.height, 0, rrect.height - 10);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) 
  {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: _side.scale(t),
        borderRadius: _borderRadius * t,
      );
}
```