# How do I build a customised floating dialogue container

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

How do I build message or alert dialogue with flutter to be pointing to a particular widget or icon like the one in the image below?

[image: Alert Dialogue]

I have tried overlays but the kind of result I was looking for. The pointed part of the container is what I find difficult

Comment: try checking custom-tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its possible using `Dialog` because apparently the `showDialog` does not have the `position` parameter and using the `Positioned` widget is not very ideal so it may be complex.

I will however demonstrate an alternative method to achieve this using `PopupMenuItems` instead as we can use the `position` parameter in the `showMenu` method.

First lable a position variable, lets say starting at (0,0) for now.

```
Offset _tapPosition = Offset.zero;
```

Instead of `IconButton` widget, you have to use `GestureDetector` because it is capable of getting the `tap position (TapDownDetails)` on the screen.

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails position) {
      _getTapPosition(position);
    },
    onTap: () {
      _showTips(context);
    },
    child: const Icon(Icons.question_mark_rounded),),
```

So now that we have the `TapDownDetails` of the click from GestureDetector, we will use a function named `_getTapPosition` to render that position globally so we can access it and update the `_tapPosition` variable.

```
void _getTapPosition(TapDownDetails tapPosition) {
  final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  setState(() {
    _tapPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(tapPosition.globalPosition);
  });
}
```

Now we can call the widget to popup at where the button was clicked using the `position` parameter of the `showMenu`:

```
  void _showTips(context) async {
    final RenderObject? overlay =
        Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();
    final menuSelected = await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(_tapPosition.dx, _tapPosition.dy, 50, 50),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 80, overlay!.paintBounds.size.width,
            overlay.paintBounds.size.height),
      ),
      items: [
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1,
          //enabled: false,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Amount may vary slightly due to rounding.',
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.close),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    switch (menuSelected) {
      case 1:
        return;
    }
  }
```

You can use the `enabled: false` parameter to avoid the select look when tapping.

See full demo on DartPad here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=266c569ee28cb0426418aefadff26923

Comment: How about the pointed part of the popup, how do I get that there?

Comment: You may need to use a package like [custom_pop_up_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_pop_up_menu) or follow this guide: [How to create a custom popup menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811115/how-to-create-a-custom-popup-menu-with-flutter)

Comment: You can also try this: [Popup with an arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867077/flutter-popup-with-an-arrow)